# Would forked repository be removed from blocked github user?

Tags: github, git-fork

Is there any way to remove forked repository from github? This happens because there is no email provided by the github user who fork a repository. If I block the user, would that forked repository be removed from his account? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/building-a-strong-community/blocking-a-user-from-your-personal-account):

> When you block a user:
>
> - The user stops following you
> - The user stops watching your repositories
> - The user's stars and issue assignments are removed from your repositories
> - The user is removed as a collaborator on your repositories
> - You're removed as a collaborator on their repositories
> - Their sponsorship of you is cancelled
>
> After you've blocked a user, they cannot:
>
> - Send you any notifications, including by @mentioning your username
> - Follow you or see your content in their activity feed
> - Invite you as a collaborator on their repositories
> - Invite you as a collaborator on a security advisory
> - Cross-reference your repositories in comments
> - Fork, watch, or star your repositories
> - Sponsor you
>
> In repositories you own, blocked users also cannot:
>
> - Open issues or send pull requests
> - Comment on issues, pull requests, or commits
> - Add or edit wiki pages

To answer your question, the already forked repositories will remain on the blocked user account.

Comment: In that case, is there anyway to remove all the forks from my repository?

Comment: I would say: No. In Github, forking a repository means making a full copy. Do you have a license on your source code? If not read : [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: @OrtomalaLokni: Do you also know, if blocked user can still pull new commits of my repository into their fork? I understand that their fork (which was created before the ban) remains. I also think that this is fair, because this happened before the ban and maybe they even have added own content, so deleting that would be rude. But can they still sync? The documentation only says blocked users cannot "follow or see [...] content in their activity feed". But this does not rule out that they can still pull new content.